# Google Forms Upload files to a New folder based on the Last Name and First Name values Submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form with 4 fields

1. Email
2. First Name
3. Last Name
4. Uploaded files button

I want to have a folder created for each form submission with a "Last Name, First, Name" naming convention and allow for multiple submissions by the same user. I keep getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response') for the following code:

```
function form(e) {
  var parentFolderId = '12NjqFgiGLf-***************************************************-KK' 
  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses(); 
  var firstname = responses[1].getResponse();
  var lastname = responses[2].getResponse(); 
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId); 
  var subfolder = parentFolder.createFolder(lastname+''+firstname); 
  var uploadedFiles = responses
    .filter(item => item.getItem().getType().toString() === 'FILE_UPLOAD'); 
  for (var x = 0; x < uploadedFiles. length; x++) {
    var uploadedFileId = uploadedFiles[x].getResponse(); 
    DriveApp. getFileById(uploadedFileId).moveTo(subfolder)
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

*UPDATE*

I found a new code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "12NjqFgiGLf***************";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  let folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.searchFolders("title contains '" + folderName + "'");
  const reg = new RegExp(`^${folderName}$|^${folderName}_\\d{2}$`);
  if (subFolder.hasNext()) {
    const folderNames = {};
    while (subFolder.hasNext()) {
      const fol = subFolder.next();
      const fName = fol.getName();
      if (reg.test(fName)) folderNames[fName] = fol;
    }
    const len = Object.keys(folderNames).length;
    if (len == 1 && folderNames[folderName]) {
      folderNames[folderName].setName(folderName + "_01");
    }
    folderName += "_" + ("00" + (len + 1)).slice(-2);
}
const folder = destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Gets the file upload response as an array to allow for multiple files.
  const fileUploads = itemResponses.filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD")
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

  // Move files to the folder.
  fileUploads.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

This code works but the folder name comes out as the first response which is the email. How would I edit this to have the file name be the third and second responses separated by comma as in "Last Name, First Name"???

Please Help. Thank you!

Comment: `e.response` causes the error, so check the value of e (is it undefined?)

Comment: @MeetTitan How do I define (e)? Please give an example. Thank You!

Comment: The input argument to your given function: `form`

Comment: Which trigger are you using the one for the form or the one for the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Cooper Form on form submit

Comment: The onFormSubmit trigger creates the event object which is what populates the first parameter which we normally write as e.  If you wish to know what it looks like run an onFormSubmit trigger and capture it with Logger.log or console.log

Comment: I always use the trigger for the spreadsheet so I'm not very familiar with the one for the form.  Plus I don't use google forms very much because I find writing my own makes for a more useful interaction.